# Count records for each table in a triple join

Tags: mysql

I have these tables:

User

```
id_user | name
1 | First
2 | Second
```

Book

```
id_book | id_user | pages
1 | 1 | 10
2 | 1 | 5
3 | 1 | 30
4 | 2 | 15
5 | 2 | 20
```

Ebook

```
id_ebook | id_user | pages
1 | 1 | 20
2 | 1 | 20
3 | 2 | 10
4 | 2 | 20
5 | 2 | 10
```

I want to create a single table that tells me for each user how many books he has, and the total of pages and how many ebooks he has and the total of pages.

Report

```
id_user | total_books | sum_pag_books | total_ebooks | sum_pag_ebooks
1 | 3 | 45 | 2 | 40
2 | 2 | 35 | 3 | 40
```

I have this code:

```
SELECT
user.name,
COUNT(book.id_book) AS 'total_books',
SUM(book.pages) AS 'sum_pag_books',
COUNT(ebook.id_ebook) AS 'total_ebooks',
SUM(ebook.pages) AS 'sum_pag_ebooks'
FROM user
LEFT JOIN book ON book.id_user = user.id_user
LEFT JOIN ebook ON ebook.id_user = user.id_user
GROUP BY user.id_user
```

But, the result is this and is not correct, how do I solve the query?
Report

```
id_user | total_books | sum_pag_books | total_ebooks | sum_pag_ebooks
1 | 6 | 90 | 6 | 120
2 | 6 | 105 | 6 | 80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try aggregating the two book tables separately, and then joining to that:

```
SELECT
    user.name,
    COALESCE(book.total_books, 0)     AS total_books,
    COALESCE(book.sum_pag_books, 0)   AS sum_pag_books,
    COALESCE(ebook.total_ebooks, 0)   AS total_ebooks,
    COALESCE(ebook.sum_pag_ebooks, 0) AS sum_pag_ebooks
FROM user
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT id_user, COUNT(*) AS total_books, SUM(pages) AS sum_pag_books
    FROM book
    GROUP BY id_user
) book
    ON book.id_user = user.id_user
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT id_user, COUNT(*) AS total_ebooks, SUM(pages) AS sum_page_ebooks
    FROM ebook
    GROUP BY id_user
) ebook
    ON ebook.id_user = user.id_user
```

The problem with your current query is that you will probably end up counting the same page more than once, if a given user has more than one book.  Doing separate aggregations as I have done above is one way to avoid this double counting problem.